# The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

In fact, the entire C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet directory is missing. I have C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ with other directories in it, but not AspNet.

I just installed the new ASP.Net Core RC 2 bits, and I am trying to follow this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/7ca517/asp-net-5-conaole-application-with-visual-studio-2015/

The first thing that threw me off is that the project type they say to load:
**ASP.NET 5 Console Application** is missing.

So I tried to download the sample solution at the top of the page. Opening it gives me this error, which I can't seem to figure out. The import referenced in the .kproj file is:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

I have tried commenting out the import, which is obviously counter intuitive, but the error still comes up:

> C:\projects\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample\src\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample.kproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\projects\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample\src\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample\AspNet5ConsoleAppExample.kproj

I have done this on two different systems and followed all prerequisites on the page:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4
In order to try to debug a console application in a Docker image on Linux. I can't get past this step on creating the project in order to even deploy through docker.

Edit: I'm essentially trying to develop worker role processes that will run .NET Core on Linux. I have docker setup already and running .NET Core code, but I can't seem to figure out how to deploy and run/debug a non web process from Visual Studio into the external Docker, because the only project type that I have found which is remotely close seems to have existed at one time (see the tutorial on csharpcorner) but is gone or missing from the new installer for RC2 (released yesterday).

Answer (score 1):

The article is about ASP.NET 5 RC1. ASP.NET Core RC2 is significantly different, so it shouldn't be a surprise that old projects don't work with it and that you can't follow old tutorials.